# Regex: negative match on group of characters?

Tags: regex

I want to create a regular expression that will match all strings starting with `0205052I0` and then where the next two characters are **not** BB.

So I want to match:

```
 0205052I0AAAAAA
 0205052I0ACAAAA
 0205052I0BCABAA
```

But not match:

```
 0205052I0BBAA
```

How can I do this with PCRE regular expressions?

I've been trying `$0205052I0^(BB)` on https://regex101.com/ but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a negative look ahead :

```
"0205052I0(?!BB).*"
```

See demo https://regex101.com/r/mO6uV4/1

Also note that you have putted the anchors at a wrong position. If you want to use anchor you can use following regex 
:

```
"^0205052I0(?!BB).*$"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case: `^` is for **NOT** in character classes, *only*. E.g.: `[^B]`. In your case, you would need something like
`0205052I0(B[^B]|[^B]B|[^B][^B])`
for the described effect.

See it in action: [RegEx 101](https://regex101.com/r/dK3dH8/1)

Which is rather cumbersome, though. The negative lookahead as suggested by @Kasra is by far the better option.

Still - if you actually wanted to capture the matched expression, you needed to add parentheses:
`(0205052I0(?:B[^B]|[^B]B|[^B][^B]).*)`
or -again- better (in the sense of readability/extensibility/maintainability)
`(0205052I0(?!BB).*)`

[RegEx 101](https://regex101.com/r/dK3dH8/2)

But if you want to keep the strings, which do not contain the **BB**, you might be better off, to match these and to replace them with nothing:  `(0205052I0(?=BB).*)`

[RegEx 101](https://regex101.com/r/dK3dH8/3)

Your sample strings having leading blanks, I didn't add anchors into the picture...
However, talking of anchors: **$** is for **end of line** - but not for **line break** as your attempt might be read...

Please comment, if and as this requires adjustment / further detail.